# Ruby arrays: %w vs %W

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the difference?

Comment: "%w" is my usual retort to people who get a little too cocky about the readability of Ruby. Works every time.

Comment: now you have an even better response :-)

Comment: As an irrelevant side note, the URL for this question confused me for a while while the page was loading.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

%w quotes like single quotes `''` (no variable interpolation, fewer escape sequences), while %W quotes like double quotes `""`.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> foo="hello"
=> "hello"
irb(main):002:0> %W(foo bar baz #{foo})
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "hello"]
irb(main):003:0> %w(foo bar baz #{foo})
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "\#{foo}"]
```

Comment: Your example show double quotes for %w too. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. When printing output, Ruby always uses double quotes and escapes characters like `#`. `'#{foo}'` and `"\#{foo}"` give you the same string, which you can verify with `'#{foo}' == "\#{foo}"` in `irb`.

Comment: It's little confusing on first see, but thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 29):

An application I've found for %W vs %w:

```
greetings = %W(hi hello #{"how do you do"})
# => ["hi", "hello", "how do you do"]
```

Comment: Although in this case, it's prob easier to just do `greetings = %w(hi hello how\ do\ you\ do)`

Answer (score 21):

%W performs normal double quote substitutions.
%w does not.

Answer (score 13):

Though an old post, the question keep coming up and the answers don't always seem clear to me. So, here's my thoughts.

%w and %W are examples of General Delimited Input *types*, that relate to Arrays. There are other types that include %q, %Q, %r, %x and %i.

The difference between upper and lower case is that it gives us access to the features of single and double quote. With single quotes and lowercase %w, we have no code interpolation (e.g. #{someCode} ) and a limited range of escape characters that work (e.g. \, \n ). With double quotes and uppercase %W we *do* have access to these features.

The delimiter used can be any character, not just the open parenthesis. Play with the examples above to see that in effect.

For a full write up with examples of %w and the full list, escape characters and delimiters - have a look at: http://cyreath.blogspot.com/2014/05/ruby-w-vs-w-secrets-revealed.html

Mark

Comment: That's a good article. I didn't realize you can make strings or other things the same way and the enclosing characters can be whatever you want. For example, `%w&readable af&`

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for Percent Strings: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings

Answer (score 2):

`%W` is used for double-quoted array elements like `%Q`, for example,

```
foo = "!"
%W{hello world #{foo}} # => ["hello", "world", "!"]
```

`%w` is used for single-quoted array elements like `%q`.

```
%w(hello world #{foo})
# => ["hello","world", "\#{foo}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = %w(a b c d)
```

**Same As**

```
array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

`%w` is a short cut symbol for the quotation mark to the string!