# Why do you use %w[] in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why would you ever use %w[] considering arrays in Rails are type-agnostic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the most efficient way to define array of strings, because you don't have to use quotes and commas.

```
%w(abc def xyz)
```

Instead of

```
['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
```

Comment: Ah makes sense :)

Answer (score 7):

Duplicate question of

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/what-does-warray-mean
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475830/what-is-the-w-thing-in-ruby
```

For more details you can follow https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/

These are the types of percent strings in ruby:

```
%w : Array of Strings
%i : Array of Symbols
%q : String
%r : Regular Expression
%s : Symbol
%x : Backtick (capture subshell result)
```

Let take some example
you have some set of characters which perform a paragraph like

```
Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
```

so when you try with

```
%w(Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!)
```

Then you will get the output like

```
=> ["Thanks", "for", "contributing", "an", "answer", "to", "Stack", "Overflow!"]
```

if you will use some sets or words as a separate element in array so you should use \ 
lets take an example

```
%w(Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack\ Overflow!)
```

output would be

```
=> ["Thanks", "for", "contributing", "an", "answer", "to", "Stack Overflow!"]
```

Here ruby interpreter split the paragraph from spaces within the input. If you give \ after end of word so it merge next word with the that word and push as an string type element in array.

If can use like below

```
%w[2 4 5 6]
```

if you will use

```
%w("abc" "def")
```

then output would be

```
=> ["\"abc\"", "\"def\""]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you didn't mark the URLs as code so they could be clicked to follow.

Answer (score 2):

%w(abc def xyz) is a shortcut for ["abc", "def","xyz"]. Meaning it's a notation to write an array of strings separated by spaces instead of commas and without quotes around them.