# Ruby -- If Elsif Else Error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm getting an error here with a simple if else chain, and I can't figure out what is going on. I started learning ruby the other day, I already know some java, and was just trying to re-write programs to learn ruby faster. I am trying to tally vowels and consonants. Anyways here is my code...

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby/
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

array = alphabet.chars.to_a
vowel = 0
cons = 0
puts array.at(1)
for i in 0...26 
    if array.at(i) == "a"
        vowel++   
    elsif array.at(i) == 'e'
        vowel++
        elsif array.at(i) == 'i'
        vowel++
    elsif array.at(i) == 'o'
        vowel++
    elsif array.at(i) == 'u'
        vowel++
    else
        cons++
    end#end if else chain
end#end for loop

puts 'Vowel: ' + vowel.to_s
puts 'Consonants: ' + cons.to_s
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:11:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif
>     elsif array.at(i) == 'e'
>          ^
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:13:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif
>       elsif array.at(i) == 'i'
>            ^
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:15:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif
>       elsif array.at(i) == 'o'
>            ^
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:17:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif
>       elsif array.at(i) == 'u'
>            ^
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:19:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_else
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:21:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
>
> C:/Users/Kelan/Documents/Programming/Ruby
>   Files/Little Programs/Alphabet.rb:25:
>   syntax error, unexpected $end,
>   expecting keyword_end puts
>   'Consonants: ' + cons.to_s
>                                  ^
>
> [Finished in 0.203 seconds]

I'm sure it's just something silly, but I've been looking forever online for help and I have heard of your great community, so I thought I would try here,

Kelan

Comment: +1 because the answers are interesting. Someday you'll understand all them. ;)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [New to Ruby - `while` loop issues in IRB](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5679808/), [problem with `if` and `else` code … in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5859170/) and probably many others as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no ++ operator in Ruby. You should have used `+= 1`
You may also want to learn about `case` statement:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

26.times do |i|
    case alphabet[i]
        when 'a' then vowel += 1
        when 'e' then vowel += 1
        when 'i' then vowel += 1
        when 'o' then vowel += 1
        when 'u' then vowel += 1
        else cons += 1
    end#end case
end#end times

puts 'Vowel: ' + vowel.to_s
puts 'Consonants: ' + cons.to_s
```

Or, even better, use method `count` from class `String`, like this:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
vowels = 'aeiou'
vowel_count = alphabet.count vowels
cons_count = alphabet.length - vowel_count
puts "Vowels: #{vowel_count}"
puts "Consonants: #{cons_count}"
```

Comment: While trying to learn Ruby, I had the same issue and it was solved by changing "i++" into "i += 1". Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also overload the case whens:
`when 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' then vowel += 1`

Comment: Thanks!! I got this too!! How can I know the error is in ++, I've been debugging it for hours!! Ruby compiler shouldn't point the error on elsif!! I've never use elsif and tot there is something wrong with my usage!!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is you're using the Java/PHP/C style increment operator. Ruby isn't down with that. You have to use `foo += 1` instead.

How about I show you a more Ruby way of doing this though?

```
# use a range to define your alphabet
alphabet = ('a'..'z').entries  #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]

# define vowels as members of an array. it's more flexible, which
# is great for things that change (what if you decide to use 'y'?)
vowels = %w{ a e i o u }  #=> ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

# keep counts all together in a hash, which I personally find cleaner
counts = { :vowels => 0, :consonants => 0 }

# even the `for` loops in ruby use the iterators, so you actually
# get better performance out of using the more user-friendly `.each`
alphabet.each do |letter|
  if vowels.include? letter
    counts[:vowels] += 1
  else 
    counts[:consonants] += 1
  end
end

puts "There were #{counts[:vowels]} vowels and #{counts[:consonants]} consonants."
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is going on with this :P (specifically the %w, and the counts parts) You are using Hashes though, right? I should probably look those up. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: `%w` is a way of defining an array quickly in ruby (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/ruby-what-does-warray-mean), and the counts hash is iterated through during each alphabet letter, and depending on if the current letter in the loop is a vowel or a consonant, the appropriate hash key value is increased by 1 (`counts[:vowels] += 1` during the first iteration (for 'A') for example). After the script finishes, `count[:vowels]` will be `5`, and `count[:consonants]` will be `21`.

Answer (score 3):

I think rather than `vowel++` and `con++`, you need to use  `vowel+=1` and `con+=1`.

Ruby does not have C-style pre/post incrementors.

Comment: That made all the difference!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another way to write the demo:

```
puts("%d vowels & %d consonants" % ('a'..'z').inject([0,0]) do |m, e|
    m[/[aeiou]/.match(e) ? 0:1] += 1; m 
  end)
```

Comment: And this is exactly what you might do if you were writing a shell script. It's much better to write code where the intent is clear, though, rather than have to leave an inline comment to explain what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

- There is an easy way of constructing the set of alphabets, using `Range`.
- Since you are using ruby, you should use internal iterators instead of the external ones. You will rarely see a `for` loop in a good program in ruby.
- `case` construction is handy in this case. You can put multiple matching patterns into one, separated by comma.
- There is no `++` or `--` operators in ruby. Use `+= 1`.
- Use `"#{  }"` notation. It's much better and faster than using `+`. In fact, you can omit `to_s` if you use it.

I would go like this:

```
vowel = 0
cons = 0
('a'..'z').each do |c|
  case c
  when 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'; vowel += 1
  else                          cons += 1
  end
end

puts "Vowel: #{vowel}"
puts "Consonants: #{cons}"
```

If I wanted a shorter one, I might go with this:

```
partition = ('a'..'z').group_by{|c| c =~ /[aeiou]/}
puts "Vowel: #{partition[0].length}"
puts "Consonants: #{partition[nil].length}"
```

Comment: I didn't know about the #{} notation, but I tried it out, and I love it!! So much easier. THANKS :)