# Does %w method in Ruby have an equivalent in SQL Server (T-SQL)?

Tags: ruby, sql-server

[%w in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/ruby-what-does-warray-mean) allows one to separate array using whitespace instead of using quotes:

**Ruby**

```
%w(one two three)
```

Is there an equivalent function in SQL Server?

**SQL Server**

```
select case when 'one' in ('one', 'two','three') then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: That isn't an array, it is a list of values. The way you posted is the way to do it in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is SQL everything is either a table, a column or a row. You can sort of do it like this:

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Number varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Numbers(Number) VALUES ('one'),('two'),('three')

SELECT CASE WHEN 'one' IN (SELECT Number FROM @Numbers) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Super-verbose, I know, but you have to consider this is a 70s-era language.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The %w method is Ruby [Syntatic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for initializing an array of strings separated by spaces.

As mentioned by Zoff, SQL being a much older language, does not have anything like this.