# Why isn't my inclusion validation passing?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

This should be a no brainer. I have a Sinatra application with RSpec and, for some reason, my validations are failing with the `inclusion` validation.

This is my code:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :department, inclusion: { in: w%(Sales, Finance, Marketing) }
end
```

This is the spec file:

```
it 'should save a valid employee' do
  employee = Employee.new(name: 'Employee One',
                        email: 'example@gmail.com',
                        title: 'Software Engineer',
                        department: 'Sales')
  expect(employee).to be_valid
end
```

This test fails because the department field is not 'included in the list'. This is aggravating because it fails no matter what field I put. Errors like these are usually from something simple.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't necessary, or particular desirable, to add tags to the title such as "(Sinatra, RSpec)". Instead, either rely on the tags you define for the question, or work them into the title naturally and not artificially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%w` is a short-cut for building array of strings. I think you are trying to build an array of strings like this:

```
["Sales", "Finance", "Marketing"]
```

In that case the correct form of using `%w` would be:

```
%w(Sales Finance Marketing)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/ruby-what-does-warray-mean) for more information on `%w` syntax in Ruby.

Also, look at the [Rails Documentation for inclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) where `%w` is used correctly.

So, to solve your problem, change your `Employee` class to look like this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :department, inclusion: { in: %w(Sales Finance Marketing) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a syntax error, I believe `w%` should be `%w`.

Your `%w` syntax is conflicting with your actual list. The `%w` makes commas not necessary and actually adds them to your list (which is not what you want). Remove them.

```
 %w(Sales, Finance, Marketing)
 => ["Sales,", "Finance,", "Marketing"]
```

vs

```
%w(Sales Finance Marketing)
 => ["Sales", "Finance", "Marketing"]
```