# Checking if an element exists inside an array created with %w(), Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know I can [use %w() as a shortcut to create an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/what-does-warray-mean). E.g. these should be equivalent:

```
FOO = %w(dog, cat)
BAR = ["dog", "cat"]
```

But when I use `include` to check [what's included in these arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986386/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-an-array-in-ruby):

```
FOO = %w(dog, cat)
BAR = ["dog", "cat"]

puts FOO.include? "dog" #false
puts BAR.include? "dog" #true
```

The first `puts` returns `false` while the second one returns `true`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't use commas with `%w`, otherwise it is including the string `dog,`.

Comment: @iBug, Adam may feel that your choice of name reflects your purpose in life. (Couldn't let it pass. :-) Perhaps the two comments can be deleted, after which you can shake hands (er, bump elbows) and this comment will vanish as well.

Answer (score 5):

No these arrays are not equivalent

```
FOO = %w(dog, cat)
BAR = ["dog", "cat"]
```

But these are

```
FOO = %w(dog cat)       # note that the `%w` syntax doesn't need commas.
BAR = ["dog", "cat"]
```

That said, your first version does not `FOO.include? "dog"` because it includes `"dog,"` and `"cat"`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @spickermann's answer, printing the array themselves is often more than enough to identify the issue.

Ruby has a [built-in method `p`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/p) that prints out any object in a "representative" format, similar to Python's `repr()`.

```rb
FOO = %w(dog, cat)
p FOO  # => ["dog,", "cat"]
#                ^ hey, bro?
```