# Sequel Grep using variables as matcher

Tags: ruby, grep, sequel

I'd like to do a query using the Sequel's `Models` object. I'd like the pattern to match certain variables value like so:

```
Models::Show.grep(:name, %w'#{var1} #{var2}')
```

But unfortunately, the Models.grep instance method seems not to be working this way. It query as following:

```
SELECT * FROM "shows" 
WHERE (("name" LIKE '#{titre_fr}' ESCAPE '\') 
OR ("name" LIKE ' {titre_en}' ESCAPE '\'))
```

Is there a way to make the function work with variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as below :

```
Models::Show.grep(:name, %W(#{var1} #{var2}))
```

Demo example :

```
a = 2
b = 3
%W(#{a} #{b}) # => ["2", "3"]
```

Read this also [***Ruby arrays: %w vs %W***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690794/ruby-arrays-w-vs-w).

Comment: I just tried it, getting the same result. is the W case sensitive ?

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp Can you give the method documentation link..?

Comment: Edited my first comment. You will find the doc here http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-grep

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp what is var1 and var2 ?

Comment: Its a variable inside an array. But in the end, I think my error was not making the w upper-case. Changed it and now it seems to work as intended.

Comment: I think adding the 2 % makes it match any records with the characters between them. It results in thousands of queries (I have stopped the process in case I get an overflow). Your first answer was better for me, along with a precision that W must be upper-case !

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp let me know which one works for you. i will update it in my answer.. as i am not aware of what's going on there..

Comment: Models::Show.grep(:name, %W(#{var1} #{var2})) works, and W must be upper-case

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
Models::Show.grep(:name, %w'#{var1} #{var2}')
```

Is using single quotes. Change to double quotes and it will work

```
Models::Show.grep(:name, %w"#{var1} #{var2}")
```