# Why doesn't interpolation of constants work with percent notation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

This doesn't work:

```
FOOBAR = 'foobar'
%W{ FOOBAR }

output: ["FOOBAR"]
```

However, the constant gets interpolated correctly by:

```
"#{FOOBAR}"
output: "foobar"
```

Comment: It's not just constants; try it with variables Think about it: `%w{...}` wouldn't be of much use if it tried to interpolate everything between the braces.

Comment: Got it... You still need `#{ ... }` around the constant

Comment: what you want is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/690826/2767755) and [this](http://cyreath.blogspot.in/2014/05/ruby-w-vs-w-secrets-revealed.html).

Comment: compare the output of:  `%W{ FOOBAR #{FOOBAR} }`

Comment: What would be the use of a notation that interpolates every word? Wouldn't that just be the same as `[FOOBAR]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misusing `%W` literal. From [book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals):

> %W - Interpolated Array of words, separated by whitespace

so it doesn't have anything to do with interpolation.